# AKKA HTTP + AKKA stream 100% CPU utilization

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I have a web API exposing one GET endpoint using Akka HTTP and, the logic that it takes the parameter form the requester go and call external web service using AKKA Streams and based on the response it goes and query another endpoint also using akka stream.

first external endpoint call looks like this

```
def poolFlow(uri: String): Flow[(HttpRequest, T), (Try[HttpResponse], T), HostConnectionPool] =
    Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[T](host = uri, 80)

def parseResponse(parallelism: Int): Flow[(Try[HttpResponse], T), (ByteString, T), NotUsed] =

    Flow[(Try[HttpResponse], T)].mapAsync(parallelism) {
      case (Success(HttpResponse(_, _, entity, _)), t) =>
        entity.dataBytes.alsoTo(Sink.ignore)
          .runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)
          .map(e => e -> t)

      case (Failure(ex), _) => throw ex
    }

def parse(result: String, data: RequestShape): (Coord, Coord, String) =
    (data.src, data.dst, result)

val parseEntity: Flow[(ByteString, RequestShape), (Coord, Coord, String), NotUsed] =
    Flow[(ByteString, RequestShape)] map {
      case (entity, request) => parse(entity.utf8String, request)
    }
```

and the stream consumer

```
val routerResponse = httpRequests
  .map(buildHttpRequest)
  .via(RouterRequestProcessor.poolFlow(uri)).async
  .via(RouterRequestProcessor.parseResponse(2))
  .via(RouterRequestProcessor.parseEntity)
  .alsoTo(Sink.ignore)
  .runFold(Vector[(Coord, Coord, String)]()) {
    (acc, res) => acc :+ res
  }

routerResponse
```

then I do some calculations on routerResponse and create a post to the other external web service,

Second external Stream Consumer

```
def poolFlow(uri: String): Flow[(HttpRequest, Unit), (Try[HttpResponse], Unit), Http.HostConnectionPool] =
    Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[Unit](host = uri)

val parseEntity: Flow[(ByteString, Unit), (Unit.type, String), NotUsed] = Flow[(ByteString, Unit)] map {
    case (entity, _) => parse(entity.utf8String)
  }

  def parse(result: String): (Unit.type, String) = (Unit, result)

val res = Source.single(httpRequest)
      .via(DataRobotRequestProcessor.poolFlow(uri))
      .via(DataRobotRequestProcessor.parseResponse(1))
      .via(DataRobotRequestProcessor.parseEntity)
      .alsoTo(Sink.ignore)
      .runFold(List[String]()) {
        (acc, res) => acc :+ res._2
      }
```

The Get Endpoint consume the first stream and then build the second request based on the first response,

Notes:

1. the first external service is fast 1-2 seconds time, and the second's external service is slow 3-4 seconds time.
2. the first endpoint is being queried using `parallelism=2` and the second endpoint is being queried using `parallelism=1`
3. The Service is running on AWS ECS Cluster, and for the test purposes it is running on a single node

the problem,

that the web service work for some time but the CPU utilization get higher by dealing with more request, I would assume something to do with back pressure is being triggered, and the CPU stays highly utilized after no request is being sent also which is strange.

Does anybody have a clue whats going on

Comment: You should take a thread dump to see what is happening.